# xfbml like button hide the possibility to add a comment to the like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, xfbml

I added a like button in a facebook application (not iframe in order to capture the liked evenment...),
and when a user click on like, then he has the possibility to add a comment to the like.

I want to hide/remove this possibility to adda comment when he click on like.

Do you know if it's possible and how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set a fixed height and overflow hidden on the div that contains your like button so that it is hidden after the user clicks 'like'.

Answer (score 1):

I added these CSS classes to my css file and it got rid of the comment box for me.

```
.fb_edge_widget_with_comment .fb_edge_comment_widget .fb_ltr {
display: none !important;
}
```