# Hide comment box on facebook like

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I am wanting to have the facebook like button, but allow no comments to be added.

I have been trying via the following:

[xfbml like button hide the possibility to add a comment to the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276256/xfbml-like-button-hide-the-possibility-to-add-a-comment-to-the-like) - doesnt work

also tried using the following on random classes/id's

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    $(".classname").hide();
  });
```

and also via `document.getElementById("u_0_2").style.display="none";`

Using any of the html/iframe/xfbml methods, what exact code is needed to stop the comments box being displayed?

Comment: What is the code you are using to make the comments box appear?

Comment: As I mentioned - I have tried using each of the html5/iframe/xfbml methods of facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ - and then trying to find the appropriate id/style of the iframe to style as hidden using the methods described.